# Anchor tag is larger than an auto sizing img

Tags: html, css

Consider the following code:

```css
.section {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100%;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200"/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200"/>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

The auto sizing `div` wrapper makes sure the image won't go beyond the section `div` height (100px), it does its job and the last two images work great. But once an anchor is added it pushes the next image away, something like the anchor width is still the original width of the image instead of the shrunk down width. How do you fix the anchor width too large issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work if you set `display: contents;` to the anchor links and the `wrapper` class.

Comment: Thanks. I tried if I add `display: contents` to the anchor, the anchor does shrink to image width, but there are still spaces there pushing the next image away. If I also change the `wrapper` class to `display: contents`, the spaces are gone but there is no padding anymore from the `wrapper`.

Comment: You may acheave the same effect by adding `margin: 20px;` to the `img` tags.